# Using pip with two --extra-index-url arguments that both point to the same domain

Tags: python, pip

We use our own python package index at my office, and we're trying to add a new one. When I try to specify both indices at the same time, I get prompted to log in, but if I use only one at a time I don't.

For example:

```
$ pip install --user --upgrade \
    --extra-index-url https://<api token>:@packagecloud.io/2rs2ts/oldrepo/pypi/simple \
    --extra-index-url https://<other api token>:@packagecloud.io/2rs2ts/newrepo/pypi/simple \
    mypackage
Collecting mypackage
User for packagecloud.io:
```

But if I specify just one of either of those `--extra-index-url` arguments then I download my package just fine.

I'm 99% certain that I am passing the arguments correctly, since [it's specified with an `append` action in the source](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/master/pip/cmdoptions.py#L228-L238). So I think the problem is that both of these index URLs are from `packagecloud.io`... but I could be wrong. Either way, how can I use both of my repos?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Apparently this is a bug in pip. The HTTP basic auth information is not stored correctly when specifying multiple `--extra-index-url`s that point to the same domain. [I filed an issue](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3931), but in the meantime, there is a workaround. By specifying one of the `--extra-index-url`s as the `--index` instead, and adding PyPI as an `--extra-index-url`, I was able to download my package successfully:

```
$ pip install --user --upgrade \
    --index https://<api token>:@packagecloud.io/2rs2ts/oldrepo/pypi/simple \
    --extra-index-url https://<other api token>:@packagecloud.io/2rs2ts/newrepo/pypi/simple \
    --extra-index-url https://pypi.python.org/simple \
    mypackage
Collecting mypackage
  Downloading https://packagecloud.io/2rs2ts/newrepo/pypi/packages/mypackage-1.0.0-py2-none-any.whl (52kB)
etc. etc.
```

Edit: [a fix](https://github.com/pypa/pip/commit/a90dd11e3f42783a8845c33fd2194bbf5b5c0d6c#) for this problem has been merged and made available as of pip 21.2 (I think; I haven't tried because this hasn't been relevant to me in a while.) If you are experiencing this issue, try updating pip first before using my workaround, since my workaround will only let you get one extra use of the domain.

Comment: Hi @2rs2ts this is not working for me with Azure DevOps Artifact Registry. I have tested it with pip==20.0.2, 21.2.1, 21.3.1. If I just use one extra-index-url it works, so it looks related

Comment: @WaterKnight sorry I can't help with that. The best way to get help is to ask a new question, reference mine, and show how your situation is different and thus not a duplicate. I wish you the best of luck!

Comment: In case this helps anyone else, I was still having problems with this bug with pip 22. Upgrading to pip 23 fixed it for me.

Answer (score 13):

You can also use the environment variable `PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL`. And then you have to use *space* as delimiter.

```sh
export PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL="https://user:token@repo-a/ https://user:token@repo-b/"
pip install
```

I found something about env vars here [in the docs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/configuration/#environment-variables). Based on the example about `PIP_FIND_LINKS`, I tried space and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

```
--extra-index-url
```

accepts a list (it should probably be called --extra-index-urls). Try adding your URLs comma separated, like this:

```
pip install --user --upgrade \
    --extra-index-url https://<api token>:@packagebutt.io/2rs2ts/oldrepo/pypi/simple, \
    https://<other api token>:@packagebutt.io/2rs2ts/newrepo/pypi/simple \
    mypackage
```

Comment: Thanks, this works if I make sure there is no space between the comma and the next URL.

Comment: Hm, actually, I take that back: if I uninstall the package then I get the error `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mypackage (from versions: )` `No matching distribution found for mypackage` - going back to just one index lets me install it.

Comment: Do you have another suggestion?

Comment: You may want to single quote the URLs to avoid whatever shell you are using trying to interpret any part of the string.